# get the category names only, with get_terms

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

```
<?php  
  $categories = array('bathroom', 'bar');  

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'product_cat' => $category, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
?>
```

I want to make the function above a little more dynamic. In such a way that I won't have to manually add the specific categories to the $categories variable. Instead, I need something that will get only the names of the (woocommerce product) categories, and places them in an array.

I did get the list with this:

```
$category_list_items = get_terms( 'product_cat' );

foreach($category_list_items as $category_list_item){
    echo $category_list_item->name;
}
```

But I don't know how to get this list into the first function. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the question, you are populating  `$category_list_items` as an array of category_list_item objects from your application. As a result you can turn your echo into an array of category names and then pass it to your function

```
$categories = []; //array to store all of your category names
$category_list_items = get_terms( 'product_cat' );

foreach($category_list_items as $category_list_item){
    if(! empty($category_list_item->name) ){
        array_push($categories, $category_list_item->name);
    }
}
```

Once this foreach has been run, you will now have a categories array populated to pass to your above function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could also get the slug of the category?

Comment: Is the slug simply part of the $category object ( `$category->slug` ) ? If you are making a separate array of slugs, you can just make a second array definition at the beginning of the code, and then do an array push for the slug. Otherwise, you can build an array/object within the foreach and then array push that into the category. 

Let me know which makes the most sense for your use case and I can update my answer.

Comment: yes that works, for people like me joining in after somewhat years and struggled with this subject try this: